# HttpPost - Params in url vs params as namevalue pair

Tags: java, http

Does this make any difference ? While writing a web service method , the URL way was working for me , but the entity way was returning some error. Is this both are same?

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/sampleservice?params=paramOne");
```

vs

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/sampleservice");     
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("params",
                    "ParamOne"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a difference in the HTTP request.
In first example, you send HTTP request with given URL and empty body.
In second, you send HTTP request with shorter URL but body with parameters.

If there will be different behavior on the server depends on how server (or framework it uses) handles such requests.

If you want to see a difference on the HTTP level, use some tool for inspecting ingoing and outgoing packets (requests), e.g. Wireshark.